# Нужна помощь с телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telegram

Телеграм бот на python, пользователь вводит команду /БотИли, после чего бот спрашивает первое условие, пользователь вводит его с клавиатуры, так же со 2 условием, после получения двух условий бот выберет одно из них рандомно и выведет пользователю.
Пример:
Пользователь: /БотИли
Бот: Введите первое условие:
Пользователь: Кактус
Бот: Введите 2 условие:
Пользователь: Розы
Бот: Я думаю Розы

Перебрал кучу вариантов, никак не пойму как сделать:)

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста больше кода для понимания.

Comment: Eсть два варианта, хранить историю ввода пользователя или некий флаг ввода.
В случае с флагом, например при ввода команды устанавливаете в глобальный массив `users[user].flags.wait_or_first_arg = True`, после кактуса `users[user].flags.wait_or_first_arg = False` `users[user].flags.wait_or_second_arg = True` и т.д.

Comment: вам все равно какую библиотеку использовать?

Comment: Я использую pyTelegramBotAPI, но могу рассмотреть и другие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу поделиться примером с использованием FSM и библиотеки aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
import random

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class UserChoice(StatesGroup):
    question1 = State()
    question2 = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["БотИли"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await UserChoice.question1.set()
    await message.answer("Введите первое условие:")


@dp.message_handler(state=UserChoice.question1)
async def state_q1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['q1'] = message.text
    await UserChoice.question2.set()
    await message.answer("Введите второе условие:")


@dp.message_handler(state=UserChoice.question2)
async def state_q2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['q2'] = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Я думаю {random.choice(list(data.values()))}")
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, позже попробую разобрать и на pyTelegramBotAPI попробывать